# Exponential Generating Function for $\frac{1}{2-\tan{x}-\sec{x}}$?

Tags: generating-functions

I'm interested in finding a nice exponential generating function, $g$, for
$$\frac{1}{2-\tan{x}-\sec{x}}.$$
The sequence listed over here on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A185323) is actually... very nasty and hard to compute.
Surely, this cannot be the best possible EGF out there? Perhaps a different way may be to perform Taylor expansion, but I'm not sure how to best approach that method. Can someone give me some advice on how I can find a better generating function?

Comment: ouch..... i see. I'm going to try my best with taylor expansion, but if that doesn't work I suppose I'll have to accept it as is.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a formula for the coefficients of that function?

Comment: yeah, but something neater than OEIS if possible.

Comment: Well I mean this is necessarily more complicated than the Euler numbers https://oeis.org/A000111 so how good an answer are you expecting?  Certainly we have $T_n =  \sum_{k = 1}^n \binom{n}{k} E_k \cdot T_{n - k}$ where $(T_n)$ is your sequence and $(E_k)$ is the Euler numbers.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough - I was originally wondering if there was a closed exponential generating function that's neater than the Euler numbers used in the first formula listed in OEIS. If possible, I want to avoid any kind of recursion! Though, I don't know if that's doable.

Comment: A "closed exponential generating function" *for what*?  The function $\frac{1}{2 - \tan(x) - \sec(x)}$ that appears in the question is the exponential generating function of the sequence $1, 1, 3, 14, 87, \ldots$ whose OEIS page you linked.  Apparently this is not what you want; so what *do* you want?